# How can I get a <div> to float on top of two other <div>s if the space is too narrow for all three to stay side-by-side?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a progress bar consisting of two `<div>`s side by side, floated to the right inside a `<dd>`. To the left of the progress bar, I have some text inside another `<div>`. If the `<dd>` gets too narrow, I want the `<div>` containing text to go on top of the progress bar, and not break into two lines.

I am using bootstrap.css with no modifications:

```css
.col-6 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.my-0 {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.py-2 {
  padding-top: 0.5rem !important;
}

.float-left {
  float: left !important;
}

.float-right {
  float: right !important;
}

.bg-success {
  background-color: #28a745 !important;
}

.bg-danger {
  background-color: #dc3545 !important;
}
```

```html
<dd class="col-6 my-0">
  <div class="float-left">Some text</div>
  <div class="py-2 float-right bg-success" style="width:10px;"></div>
  <div class="py-2 float-right bg-danger" style="width:90px;"></div>
</dd>
```

I have tried adding `z-index` to the `<div>`s, but haven't been able to acheive the effect I want.

How to do?

Comment: add your css also

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `flex` I think.

Look at your code.

```
<dd class="col-6 my-0">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="float-left">Some text</div>
    <div class="ml-auto">
        <div class="py-2 float-right bg-success" style="width:10px;"></div>
        <div class="py-2 float-right bg-danger" style="width:90px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</dd>
```

Comment: I couldn't get your suggestion to solve my problem.